# Get maximum date from database on conditional basis

Tags: sql, oracle

I hae a flag and date combination in my table, so my table is like this

```
DATE        FLAG 
----------------
01-JAN-18   1
02-JAN-18   0.5
03-JAN-18   3
06-JAN-18   9
```

I want an SQL query for this table which returns me 0 or 1 for a particular date based on weather the previous maximum date in table was with flag 0 or not

I have tried this- first I get previous day for a particular day-

```
max_date = select max(date) from table where date < input_date;
```

after getting this date I get the flag for this date

```
select flag from table where date=max_date
```

I want a smart/better way to do this

Comment: what do you need as the output? what have you tried so far? please add these details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag` with a `case` expression.

```
select dt,flag,case when lag(flag) over(order by dt) = 0 then 1 else 0 end as prev_zero_or_not
from tbl
```

Comment: I want my code to be understandable to others with basic SQL knowledge like me, like I have to go and read about how lag works if I need to make changes in query or something else

Comment: @pratish_v: that is a really bad reason to not use modern SQL features that have been around for over 20 years in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks I am finally using lag as it is efficient than any other of my solutions

Answer (score 0):

`LAG` is a good option, but if you wish to not use any analytical functions, you may have to use multiple joins.

You want a case where the previous flag value is zero, but you don't bother to give one example or expected output in your question. I have added it anyway.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d6fce/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table yourtable as 
select TO_DATE ('01-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') dt, 1 flag from dual UNION ALL
select TO_DATE ('02-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY'), 0.5 from dual UNION ALL
select TO_DATE ('03-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY'), 3  from dual UNION ALL
select TO_DATE ('06-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY'), 9  from dual UNION ALL
select TO_DATE ('08-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY'), 0  from dual UNION ALL
select TO_DATE ('11-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY'), 7  from dual UNION ALL
select TO_DATE ('14-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY'), 12 from dual
```

**Query 1**:

```
     SELECT s.dt,s.flag,
           CASE
             WHEN t.flag = 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END is_prev_dt_flag_zero
    FROM   yourtable t
           RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT a.dt,MAX(a.flag) flag,
                              Max(b.dt) prev_date
                       FROM   yourtable a
                              LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable b
                                     ON b.dt < a.dt
                       GROUP  BY a.dt) s
                   ON t.dt = s.prev_date
    ORDER  BY s.dt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d6fce/4/0)**:

```
|                   DT | FLAG | IS_PREV_DT_FLAG_ZERO |
|----------------------|------|----------------------|
| 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z |    1 |                    0 |
| 2018-01-02T00:00:00Z |  0.5 |                    0 |
| 2018-01-03T00:00:00Z |    3 |                    0 |
| 2018-01-06T00:00:00Z |    9 |                    0 |
| 2018-01-08T00:00:00Z |    0 |                    0 |
| 2018-01-11T00:00:00Z |    7 |                    1 |
| 2018-01-14T00:00:00Z |   12 |                    0 |
```